# SonarQube not starting without embedded database

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I've tried to upgrade Sonar 3.5.1 to the latest version SonarQube 4.0. I did all the recommended upgrade steps and updated the new configuration files with proper values from the older versions.

For some reason, when I switch to a external postgres database (disabling the embedded H2) which holds our data, I always get a JNPE

```
    2013.12.19 13:43:27 ERROR o.s.s.p.PlatformLifecycleListener  Fail to start server
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.sonar.server.db.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.start(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:37) ~[EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.class:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-4.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:245) ~[Platform.class:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:193) ~[Platform.class:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:35) ~[PlatformLifecycleListener.class:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_07]
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to migrate from H2 to PostgreSQL.
Try to install a fresh new instance of SonarQube.